# SSAS MDX Script View New Calcuated Measure against a different date

Tags: ssas, mdx

I'm a real newbie to MDX.
I'm trying to learn/get my head around how to create a new measure taking an existing measure and put against next date e.g.

Sales:
20190101 Qty 100
20190102 Qty 40
new measure to show
20190102 Qty 100
20190103 Qty 40

I've tried this:

```
create member currentcube.[Measures].[Qty Previous]
as
([Dim Date].[Date ID].currentmember.prevmember,[Measures].[Qty]);
```

Which does work but only when Date Dimension is used.
The existing Sales measure will work with any dimension (Time, Product, Location), how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not explicitly using a Date member your existing measures will be aggregating at the All level.

Answer (score -2):

you can fix that in your usage dimension in VS